# optimizing search engine in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, search-engine, nopcommerce

I have a task to optimize search engine in asp.net ecommerce store based on nopcommerce tempate. 
I would like to hear on what should I pay most attention to improve the search engine and to deliver faster results, since current search engine is taking forever to display results.
Full Text Search is one of the options to be implemented too.
Thanks in advance, Laziale

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the best way will be reading this document provided by Google which tells you what are the most important tweaks you should pay attention to, i used it myself and was very rewarded indeed:

http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf

Comment: The OP's question is not about SEO, is about optimizing the internal search engine of nopCommerce (http://www.nopcommerce.com). This answer shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that all search queries are thru database
2. Make sure that all the search fields have the proper indecies
3. Return as minimum info as needed (probably create stored procedures)
4. Look at your search queries, perhaps they can be rewritten an optimized
5. Profile your .net code and find the place where it slow and optimize it
6. Cache your results or even sql queries
7. For FULL TEXT SEARCH look at Lucene.NET

Comment: Views should be avoided and instead stored procedure should be used. This will have an option to filter the records and to keep the index small by using sub-queries...

Comment: **Return as minimum info as needed** Why? This means restricting the user to go back to database again and again....?Give provision to the user to input the page record length

Comment: **Look at your search queries, perhaps they can be rewritten an optimized** Any tips ?

Comment: **Cache your results or even sql queries** Why ? One side you are saying to go to database and other side you are saying to cache it. The contents can vary according to the search keywords...

Comment: **For FULL TEXT SEARCH look at Lucene.NET** Which index will you like to suggest in which context ?

Comment: agree about stored procedures, by minimum I mean minimum that is appropriate... e.g. no need to search by such columns as createdby, createdon, updatedby, updatedon... etc... by look at your queries. That depends on situation, perhaps they are not the ideal... like for example every query you counting the average number of something.. so probably you can add an extra field and update it per insert or delete (triggers sql)

Comment: **Profile your code and find the place where it slow and optimize it** Any source you will like to suggest to profile the slow queries ?

Comment: not sure I fully understand you, I mean SQL Index for fields that take part in search, and for Lucene.net, have a look at http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/

Comment: and what about the weak point in source code? e.g. select all and filter in code behind... so I proposed that variant also

Comment: Guys, thx for the discussion. So do you think Lucene.NET is the way to go if I want to include full text search? Thx

Comment: Other person is curious to know about real/true database tips

Comment: Just heard about it from you first time. I will let you know once i get some healthy knowledge about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Skip the EF and have your own data layer, at least for the purpose of Search Optimization.